# Cheap solution for exposing multiple HTTP services in K8s cluster (AWS EKS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm pretty new to k8s and I'm trying to figure out how to expose to Internet, multiple HTTP services, in cheap manner. Currently I'm using AWS EKS cluster with managed node groups, so the cheap way will be not to provision any kind ELB as it cost. Also I would like those services to be in private subnets so just f.ex only Ingress Resource will be exposed and the nodes will stay private. One load balancer per svc is definitely not an option as it will break down my budget

The options I consider:

- Using K8s ingress resources (to be precise: Istio Ingress controller). But the downside of that is, when we creating ingress resource, AWS create Load Balancer for which I will need to pay.
- Run node groups in public subnets, and create K8s Services of type NodePort so I could reach service using NodeIP:NodePort (NodePort will be specific for each service). The downside of that I will need to remember all IPs and ports assigned to each service. I can live with one service but when the number increase that will be pretty awful to remember.
- At last, without any other option is to create one load balancer with public IP and also create Ingress controller with Istio. So I will reach each services by single DNS name of Load Balancer and I will route to services by request path.

Looking forward to any solution and inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any magic here. Option 1 and 3 are basically one and the same (unless I am missing something). As you pointed out I don't think option 2 is viable for the reasons you call out. You have a number of options to go with. I don't know the Istio ingress (but I assume it will be fine). We often see customers using either the [NGINX ingress](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/network-load-balancer-nginx-ingress-controller-eks/) or the [ALB ingress](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html).

All of these options require a Load Balancer.